# Why won't my client connect to my server?

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to make a simple chat server that sends an object, Message between them. My server creation/connection code is

```
 IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, port);
    Socket serverSocket = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily,
    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Socket running on port " + port);
    System.Console.WriteLine(ipHost);
    serverSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Accepting Connections");
    serverSocket.Listen(10);
    while (true)
    {
         Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();
         Thread t = new Thread(() => Login.login(clientSocket));
         System.Console.WriteLine("Client accepted.");
    }
```

and my client creation/connection code is

```
System.Console.WriteLine("attempting to connect");
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
System.Console.WriteLine("tesinft3");
clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(server's external IP address), port);
System.Console.WriteLine("tesinft4");
System.Console.WriteLine("Connected to Server");
```

When I try to connect the client to the server I get attempting to connect and testinft3 and that's it. After about 30 seconds they appear again, but they still won't connect. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the client running on the same machine as the server?

Comment: Yes. I am intending to have it run on two different computers on two different networks, but, for now, yes.

Comment: Have you tried using the server's internal IP address (or 127.0.0.1)? If that works, you're probably looking at a routing issue.

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: So I used my old Python client code to try to connect to my server and it gave me the error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Student\Downloads\Andrew 3\Andrew\Server\clientcode.py", line 20, in <module>
    s.connect((host, port))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond" How can I fix this?

Comment: I added in the InvalidCatchException e thing to my catch in my code and I got the time out error for my C# client as well. Any idea how to fix? And when I ran it on two different machines on two different networks I got a time out error.